# How to mask yes/no when using ColdFusion YesNoFormat

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Is there a way to mask the output of YesNoFormat() so that instead of 'yes' and 'no' it displays 'active' and 'inactive'.

```
   <cfset currstatus = YesNoFormat(usrStatus)> //Returns Yes. I want this to return active
```

Before displaying i can do a if/else check: if "Yes" display "active" else display "inactive". but I want to avoid this as I have to do this in lot of places so just want to reach out to the community if their is any masking capability/technique available for this function. If not is there any alternative. Comment if you need more details

Comment: What version of CF?

Comment: And where does usrStatus come from? If it's only used here, can it just be set there?

Comment: @Shawn - CF10. userstatus/ledgerstatus/accountstatus there are many such variables they are coming from a db query in a cfc and then displayed in a datable(datacol header). I have to display various status' like active/inactive, blocked/unblocked, credit/debit etc based on the loaded page. Based on the answers that are received below I think it would be best to create my own function(as suggested by Sebastian Zartner) and refactor my code. Thanks

Comment: You should append that extra explanation to the question. Explains more why and what kind of alternative you're looking for ...

Comment: If those come from a query, there may be a need to account for NULL values, which may also require some special handling. At the very least, you'll probably have to take empty strings into account (which `yesNoFormat()` does), so make sure you deal with that. True Booleans make for easy passing. I'd definitely go the route of rolling your own function here, and CF10 will let you use the ternary operator (`BooleanVal?YesResult:NoResult`), which makes for cleaner code.

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ff7

Answer (score 8):

Single line version of the if/else statement:

```
<cfset currstatus = usrStatus ? "active" : "inactive">
```

Comment: +1. As long as `usrStatus` is a value CF translates to true/false, you do not need YesNoFormat(). Just a simple ternary operation.

Answer (score 3):

`YesNoFormat()` unfortuantely [doesn't allow to output different strings](https://cfdocs.org/yesnoformat).
If you need that functionality in a lot of places, you should therefore create your own function like this:

```
<cffunction name="boolToString" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="boolVar" type="boolean" required="yes">
  <cfreturn boolVar ? "active" : "inactive">
</cffunction>
```

Comment: For more flexibility, uou could also make the two values,"active"/"inactive", function arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `YesNoFormat(value, [maskvalue1, maskvalue2])`

but you can do `YesNoFormat(value) ? "maskvalue1" : "maskvalue2"`

and since `value` must be a number or boolean you end up with

`((value) ? "maskvalue1" : "maskvalue2")` in your case

`<cfset currStatus = ((usrStatus) ? "active" : "inactive") />`

Answer (score 1):

the only way i can see is to use a if statement.

```
<cfif usrStatus>
   <cfset currstatus = "active">
<cfelse>
  <cfset currstatus = "inactive">
</cfif>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have this. Wish we had something like YesNoFormat(value, [maskvalue1, maskvalue2])>

Comment: I think you are trying to externalize the active/inactive string. I might be tempted to use `css-content` and just add an html class. Alternatively, if `currstatus` is coming from a cfc, I might be tempted to add a function to that class. Something like `doFormattedStatus()`. I am not feeling real strong about either one of those. I would have to know more about the overall concern.

Comment: userstatus/ledgerstatus/accountstatus there are many such variables they are coming from a db query in a cfc and then displayed in a datable(datacol header). I have to display various status' like active/inactive, blocked/unblocked, credit/debit etc based on the loaded page. I would give Sebastian's approach a shot and refactor my code. Thanks